# MySQL Syntax error exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm not able to execute the query here.It says the above mentioned error.I have tried with 'Select * from customer' query and it is working.I can't figure out where am i going wrong.Please help and thanks in advance.

The full query is- SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNTRY,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FIRST_NAME='SHIVAM';

The error message is- com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErr orException: Unknown coloumn 'SHIVAM' in 'where clause'

```
DefaultTableModel model;
model=(DefaultTableModel)tblSearchCustomer.getModel();
try{
 Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
 Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/divign","root","password");
 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

 String sfld=(String) searchfldCB.getSelectedItem();
//this stands for Search Field(ComboBox)
 String op=(String) opCB.getSelectedItem();
//this stands for operator(ComboBox) 
 String crit=criteriaTF.getText();
 //this stands for criteria
 String query="SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNTRY,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE" + sfld+""+op+""+crit+" ;";
 //This Query is not Executing
 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
 while(rs.next()) {
     model.addRow (new Object[ ] {

       rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getInt(5),
       rs.getString(6),rs.getInt(7)
     } );

 }
rs.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
 }
catch(Exception e){   
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full query and error ?

Comment: Please post the generated query and the error message. As a guess, you almost certainly are missing some spaces in `WHERE" + sfld+""+op+""+crit+" ;`

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErr

orException: Unknown coloumn 

'SHIVAM' in 'where clause'

Comment: SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNTRY,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FIRST_NAME='SHIVAM' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the corrected query-

String query="SELECT       CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PASSWORD,ADDRESS,COUNTRY,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL_ADDRESS,PHONE_NUMBER FROM CUSTOMER WHERE " +sfld+" "+op+" '"+crit+"' ;";

Notice the inverted commas around crit....now if i type SHIVAM in jTextField (criteriaTF) the name will be executed in MySQL with inverted commas i.e. 'SHIVAM'

Answer (score 2):

When you generate your query, there are no single quotes in your where statement, which means you'll get `WHERE FIRST_NAME=SHIVAM`, so it tries to compare first_name to a column called SHIVAM which doesn't exist

Comment: This is the best answer so far, only because it does not offer a "solution" that continues to use dynamic SQL. It would be a much better answer if it mentioned that using a *parameterized query* would have avoided the problem in the first place, and that all of the other "solutions" are still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

String query="SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNTRY,AGE,GENDER,EMAIL_ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE" + sfld+""+op+""+crit+" ;";

In the where condition you haven't mentioned the column name to assign the value of sfld+""+op+""+crit.

You have to provide the column name next to where clause.